# Ionic - How to stop video player on slide change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ion slider with images and videos, and I am using [angular-youtube-embed](https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed) for embeding videos.
This is the slider:

```
    <ion-slides ng-if="slider.length > 0" class="slides">
      <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="item in slider">
        <img ng-if="item.image" ng-src="{{ fileServer }}/imagecache/cover/{{ item.image }}" class="cover">
        <div ng-if="item.video">
          <youtube-video video-url="item.video.original_url" player="youtubePlayer" player-vars="playerVars" class="video"></youtube-video>
        </div>
      </ion-slide-page>
    </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the player to a scope variable like this:

```
$scope.$on('youtube.player.ready', function($event, player) {
    $scope.YTPlayer = player;
});
```

and stop the video when the slide change is finished:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeEnd", function(event, data) {
    $scope.YTPlayer.stopVideo();
});
```

Greetings!!

Comment: I have tried it, but I get:  ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ionicSlidesProvider <- $ionicSlides <- ArticleController, and I have injected into my controller $ionicSlides

Comment: @Marco That´s weird , check out this plunker: [Slide Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/xanDbK?p=preview), open the console to see, in this example I handle in two ways the event and print the index